# Details row custom template with Backpack for Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-backpack

I'm working on an application where i want to show some sensor readings in real time.I have a CRUD for devices and in the details row for each entry of a device, i want to show a javascript chart which shows the readings coming from that device in real time. My problem is that the chart requires some js to be added along with the template of the details row, i cant seem to figure out where to load that js.

WHAT I'VE TRIED

I tried creating a new blade view file for the details row template and added the js just before the ending body tag, but it did'nt work.

I also tried loading the js inside the master layout blade file but it did not work as well, however in this case it did work when i loaded the chart inside the dashboard.blade.php file, but i want to load the chart inside details row. How can i solve this problem ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanx

Comment: if you can add some code of that which you have tried. That would be best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More details would be useful but here are a few things to keep in mind;

The contents of the detail row are only downloaded once you click the button. This fires an AJAX request to the server which responds back with the generated *details_row.blade.php* view. The response is essentially a DOM fragment and is not a complete HTML document of its own (i.e. there should be no body tags in the view).

You need to perform any DOM manipulations after the details row is downloaded. This could be done by including it in a script tag at the bottom of the response (bottom of *details_row.blade.php*). Additionally, if it requires an external javascript file you should include it in the list view. If you are including it in the details row blade template you must wrap your javascript in `$(document).ready(function(){`... otherwise your javascript is likely running before it is finished downloading.